# The meaning of the class $\Omega ''$ of distribution functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a very short question. I'm reading [this article](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177730150) and there they are talking about the class $\Omega ''  $ of distribution functions. I cite:

> *"The test  is consistent with respect to the class $\Omega ''$ of d.f.'s with continuous joint and marginal probability densities (p.d.)."*

That is the second sentence. I have looked it up in Google, but I have got no results. It may have an unusual notation. I appreciate if someone can explain it to me. You can keep it short. Even a link is fine by me.

Comment: It seems like it's basically what it says: $\Omega''$ is the set of CDFs which have a continuous joint density and continuous marginal densities. Presumably the dimension is obvious from context (without reading the article I'd guess that it is $2$). I don't think this notation is standard.

Comment: @Ian yes that makes sense. I thought that it had another meaning which I was missing. Thanks!!